# How to get font color code from a .docx using R?

Tags: r

I have a huge .docx document and I need to extract 3 data from it.
The document has around 9000 lines and few paragraphs have different colors.
It's an important information.
Does anybody know a function/package or a way to do this?
The color code can be in any format (Hex, RGB, or whatever), I just need to extract it to distinguish the paragraphs by color.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you unzip the directory and read the xml file (see [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-to-get-data-out-of-word-docs/) for details),  `xml_find_all(read_xml('./word/document.xml'), './/w:color')` should work

Comment: Man, it worked!! thanks a lot.
But now I have another problem. I'm trying to write it in a txt file. I've searched for some solutions, but didn't find. Any idea?
Thanks again

Comment: not sure what you mean by writing it, you mean you want to write new text with those colors? you should write this as a new question with your example input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\text.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
doc_Selection <-  wordApp$Selection()

list_Text <- list()
list_Color_Text <- list()

for(i in 1 : 40)
{
  print(i)
  error_Term <- tryCatch(wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$ActiveWindow()$Panes(1)$Pages(1)$Rectangles(i)$Range()$Select(),
                         error = function(e) NA)

  bool_Null <- !is.null(error_Term)
  bool_NA <- is.na(tryCatch(is.na(error_Term), error = function(e) NA))
  bool_NA <- length(bool_NA) != 0
  
  if(bool_Null == TRUE | bool_NA == TRUE)
  {
    break
  }
  
  list_Text[[i]] <- tryCatch(doc_Selection$Range()$Text(), error = function(e) NA)
  list_Color_Text[[i]] <- tryCatch(doc_Selection$Range()$Font()$ColorIndex(), error = function(e) NA)
}

# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex for the colors

list_Text
[[1]]
[1] "hi\r"

[[2]]
[1] "\r"

[[3]]
[1] "this is a good text\r"

[[4]]
[1] "\r"

[[5]]
[1] "\r"

[[6]]
[1] "\r"

[[7]]
[1] "here is a word document\r"

list_Color_Text

[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 6

[[4]]
[1] 0

[[5]]
[1] 0

[[6]]
[1] 0

[[7]]
[1] 3
```